# how to write sql statement in zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to write this sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM `astrology` where ((commu_time_from  >= '10:30' and commu_time_from <= '10:40') or (commu_time_to  >= '10:30' and commu_time_to <= '10:40'))
```

in zend framework ?

Comment: This http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html didn't helped you?

Comment: Are you using the Zend_Db module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this works:

```
 $model=new Default_Model_Astronomy();
 $select=$model->getMapper()->getDbTable()->getAdapter()->select();
 $select=$select->from('astrology')
                ->where("commu_time_from  >= '10:30' and commu_time_from <= '10:40'")
                ->orWhere("commu_time_to  >= '10:30' and commu_time_to <= '10:40'");
```

Answer (score 1):

so:

```
        $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
                                             'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                                             'username' => 'webuser',
                                             'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
                                             'dbname' => 'test'
                                        ));

    $select = $db->select()
            ->from("...specify table and columns ... ")
            ->where(" ...specify search criteria ... ")
            ->order(" ...specify sorting criteria ... ");
```

in your specific case:

```
        $select = $db->select()
            ->from("astrology")
            ->where("commu_time_from  >= '10:30' AND commu_time_from <= '10:40'")
            ->orWhere("commu_time_to  >= '10:30' AND commu_time_to <= '10:40'");
```

Comment: I think the OP is struggling with the exact parameters to the from and where methods.

Answer (score 0):

Using the select object from an instance of a Zend_Db_Table ($table in my case), Try this:

```
$table->select()->where('(commu_time_from >= "10:30"')
                ->where('commu_time_from <= "10:40")')
                ->orWhere('(commu_time_to >= "10:30")')
                ->where('commu_time_to <= "10:40")')
```

Note that the $table variable is the instance of Zend_Db_Table with the $_name property set to "astrology"